# Non-static private variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, static, private

I'm setting up my javascript objects like the following

```
Object1 = function() {
  var privateMember = "private value"

  return {
    publicMember: "public value"
    setPrivateMember: function(value) {
       privateMember = value;
    }
  }
}();
```

Now if I use prototypal inheritance to create new objects

```
Object2.prototype = Object1
```

And then set the private member

```
Object2.setPrivateMember("new value");
```

Then the value of private member in Object 1 changes too, so it behaves more like a static variable. Is there a way I can get private variables to not be static?

PS - I'm a self-taught programmer so my use of terminology might be a bit sketchy. Let me know if it needs clarifying

Comment: Should be using `Object2.prototype = Object1()`, or is that just a typo in the pasted code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Private variables in inherited prototypes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617139/private-variables-in-inherited-prototypes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Righto, knew I awnsered something like this before:
[Private variables in inherited prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617139/private-variables-in-inherited-prototypes/3617325#3617325)

;oP

Comment: I knew it had to have been asked before, but just couldn't find the right phrase to search for.

Cheers for the answer

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a global variable. Put var before it.

```
var privateMember = "private value";
```

Comment: This was a typo in my question. Problem still happens even when I use var

Answer (score 2):

Edited my answer, can you check if this works?

Try this -

```
Object1 = function() {  
  var privateMember = "private value"; 

  var returnVal =  {  
                publicMember: "public value",  
                setPrivateMember: function(value) {  
                privateMember = value;  
                }

           }; 
  return returnVal; 
}();
```