# .call(this) idiom in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

In some JavaScript I see:

```
var passport = require('passport')

function Strategy(options, verify) {
  //...

  passport.Strategy.call(this);
}
```

What is `passport.Strategy.call(this);` doing?

Comment: It's defining instance properties on `this`. See [Define Private field Members and Inheritance in JAVASCRIPT module pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463040/define-private-field-members-and-inheritance-in-javascript-module-pattern)

Comment: Assuming that `passport.Strategy` is a "base" class and the user-defined `Strategy` should be an "extension", it is basically giving the extended class the features of the base one

Comment: And you may find explanation on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) too

Comment: Begi: `call` Invokes the given function in with `this` defined for the invocation. This appears to be a "base-class constructor invocation". How is this defining "instance properties on this"?

Comment: You have two answers saying significantly different things, and I want to point out that they're both likely correct.  Niels correctly points out the only thing we know for certain.  `passport.Strategy` is being called with the `this` object being set to the `this` object that was used when `Strategy` was called.  That's all we can be entirely certain of.  But badsyntax is most likely correct too that the capitalization of both `Strategy`'s is means that this is being done in order to run `passport.Strategy` as a constructor function inside the `Strategy` constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of that code, this is effectively a way to execute the super constructor. Looking at the [passport-local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/lib/passport-local/strategy.js) object for example, the passport-local class's prototype inherits from the Strategy prototype. Effectively it's a "sub-class" of passport.Strategy. When you create a new instance of passport.Local, you will also want to execute the super constructor (passport.Strategy). Doing `constructor.call(context)` allows you to execute the super constructor in the context of the sub-class.

Answer (score 1):

The `.call()` function is a native javascript function which passes the context to the function. In this case the function `passport.Strategy()` is called and the context of `this` is passed.

This means that within the `passport.Strategy()` function the `this` object refers to the first passed variable to the `.call()` function.