# Javascript object member variable not cloning

Tags: javascript, html, class, object, easeljs

I'm inheriting an object from the EASELJS library.
To simplify the problem, I'm reducing the code into the minimal form.

I have a class:

```
this.TESTProg = this.TESTProg || {};

(function() {
    var _jsbutton = function(x, y, text, icon) {
        p.init(x, y, text, icon);
    };

    var p = _jsbutton.prototype = new createjs.Container();

    p.x = 0;
    p.y = 0;
    p.text = null;
    p.icon = null;

    p.init = function(x, y, text, icon) {
        this.x = 0 + x;
        this.y = 0 + y;
        this.text = "" + text;
        this.icon = null;
    };

    TESTProg._jsbutton = _jsbutton;
})();
```

Then I use it in another js object:

```
    var buttoncancel = new SJSGame._jsbutton(
            profileselConfig.cancelx,    //this is defined in another jsfile:
            profileselConfig.cancely,
            "cancel", "_cancel.png");

    console.log( buttoncancel.y );  //this gives 240

    var buttoncancel2 = new SJSGame._jsbutton(
            profileselConfig.cancelx,
            profileselConfig.cancely - 40,
            "cancel", "_cancel.png");

    console.log( buttoncancel.y );    //this gives 200
    console.log( buttoncancel2.y );   //this gives 200

    buttoncancel2.y = 100;
    console.log( buttoncancel.y );    //this now gives 200 (not changed by the second object)
    console.log( buttoncancel2.y );   //this now gives 100
```

The config file:

```
var _profileselConfig = function(){
    this.cancelx = 0;
    this.cancely = 240;
};

profileselConfig = new _profileselConfig();
```

And what am i doing wrong?

I'm already using 0 + to avoid passing the reference and it's not working. What should I do now? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe check out [EaselJS: Can somebody explain the inheritance pattern used in demos?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008421/easeljs-can-somebody-explain-the-inheritance-pattern-used-in-demos)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be calling `this.init` rather than `p.init` in your constructor.

When you call `p.init`, the `this` inside of `init` refers to the prototype. Thus, whenever you create an instance, your `p.init` call modifies the prototype for *all* `_jsbutton` objects.

That's why both buttons have the same x/y values: they both get their position from the same prototype, and the last-run constructor set the prototype values. When you set `buttoncancel2.y` outside of the constructor, you gave that instance its own `y` property, so it no longer used the shared prototype value.

If you call `this.init` in your constructor, then the `this` in `init` will refer to your newly-created instance. The instances will no longer use the shared prototype values for `x`, `y`, `text`, and `icon`.

Side note: "*I'm already using 0 + to avoid passing the reference*" -- this is not necessary, because primitive types are always copied.

Comment: Thanks, so even when my p is a new instance that doesn't differenciate the different objects. Got it